# High voltage switching transistor

Tags: high-voltage

Is there any transistor that can be used to switch voltages up to 3000 volts?
What transistor could it be?

Comment: [One of these](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv607=105&pv607=117&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007d&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) or [one of these](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv814=176&pv814=37&pv814=131&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007e&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25).

Comment: How much current does it need to switch? A high-power solution may be a [spark gap switch](http://www.amazing1.com/sparkgap.html) or a [Krytron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krytron) or related vacuum tube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametric search on Digikey reveals these:

4500V FETs: 
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv607=117&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007d&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

3600V+ IGBTs:
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv814=176&pv814=37&pv814=131&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007e&k=igbt&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Answer (score 0):

There are power transistors available in market,I dont think so that,It's voltage rating will be around 3000V. However,there are transistors,which will tolerate upto 1500V. Check out this page [STM high voltage transistor](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM100/CL822/SC94).

  You can use relays for switching high voltages.There are relays available in market,which are rated at maximum wattage.I think,relays will be suitable for switching application